# ffmpeg how to change video framerate without changing video duration?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-conversion, video-encoding

I'm trying to encode a video with a diffrent constant framerate using ffmpeg. The duration of the output file is different than the original by a 0.02 seconds which is about a frame.

How do I change the framerate without changing the duration.

I'm using this command: "ffmpeg.exe -y -i work.ts -an -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 -framerate 29.97 out.ts"

The original framerate is: 59.94 fps

Any help will be very appreciated :-)

Log:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i work.ts -an -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 -framerate 29.97 out.ts

ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'work.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:04.02, start: 31.405178, bitrate: 6430 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] profile High, level 3.2
Output #0, mpegts, to 'out.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 59.94 fps, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  240 fps= 43 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2120kB time=00:00:03.95 bitrate=4391.5kbits/s speed=0.714x
video:1940kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 9.278002%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] frame I:1     Avg QP:27.60  size: 71877
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] frame P:61    Avg QP:28.06  size: 22993
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] frame B:178   Avg QP:31.75  size:  2875
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.8%  0.0% 98.3%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] mb I  I16..4:  5.0% 11.6% 83.5%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] mb P  I16..4:  2.5%  3.6%  4.7%  P16..4: 43.1% 20.1% 10.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:15.9%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.1%  0.2%  B16..8: 22.6%  2.9%  0.5%  direct: 0.6%  skip:73.1%  L0:33.7% L1:59.3% BI: 6.9%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] 8x8 transform intra:29.6% inter:65.2%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 68.8% 68.1% 30.0% inter: 10.8% 9.5% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 10% 80%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 11% 49% 14%  4%  3%  4%  4%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12% 55% 10%  3%  3%  4%  4%  3%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 42% 35% 15%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] ref P L0: 69.3% 16.2% 11.6%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] ref B L0: 88.4%  8.8%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] ref B L1: 99.4%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0000024c3c135a00] kb/s:3968.40
```

---

```
ffProbe\ffprobe.exe work.ts

ffprobe version N-82117-gc117343 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavcodec     57. 63.103 / 57. 63.103
  libavformat    57. 55.100 / 57. 55.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.103 / 57.  0.103
  libavfilter     6. 64.100 /  6. 64.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'work.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:04.02, start: 31.405178, bitrate: 6430 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s
```

---

```
ffProbe\ffprobe.exe out.ts

ffprobe version N-82117-gc117343 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavcodec     57. 63.103 / 57. 63.103
  libavformat    57. 55.100 / 57. 55.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.103 / 57.  0.103
  libavfilter     6. 64.100 /  6. 64.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'out.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:04.00, start: 1.433367, bitrate: 4336 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
```

Comment: tried removing -an and changing the framerate from 29.97 to 30000/1001
Still got the same duration changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the original video has an odd number of frames and you reencode to half the frame rate, it is impossible to hit exactly the same length as the original. You can chose between half a frame (new framerate) more or less.

By default `ffmpeg` will chose the longer version, but by setting "-t ss.sss" you can force the shorter length.

Comment: Logical, but the OP's commands don't change framerate as `-framerate` is an input option meant for image sequences and raw streams. The output rate is set by `-r` which the OP doesn't use.